# How to identity the character (set-based)?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Recently a friend of mine has shown me a question as under

```
declare @t table(data varchar(50))
insert into @t 
 select '    
        _   
       |_  |_   '
```

God knows from where he got this idea ! How can I find that it is CL

How to do that in a set-based manner?
Thanks a lot

Comment: He got the idea from this site: http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/tc/archive/2010/01/11/TSQL-Challenge-21-Reading-recognizing-and-processing-graphical-representation-of-digits.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do it. You have to do string manipulation and the map each string to the character it represents. Check the site that posted that challenge [here](http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/tc/archive/2010/01/11/TSQL-Challenge-21-Reading-recognizing-and-processing-graphical-representation-of-digits.aspx). You have to use CTE to do it in a set based statement.
You can have a table like:

```
select ' _ | ||_|', 0 union all
select '     |  |', 1 ...
```

This will allow you to map the character to the numbers with a simple join.

I am sorry I do not post my full solution to this challenge here, but this question is still going on and they will be posting the best solution in about a month.
The whole idea of these challenges is to try to find how to do it and learn in the process.